# Find and plot peaks/maxima

Tags: image, matlab, octave, m

How can I plot the 'peak' (local maxima) in Matlab/Octave? My below code loads in an image, extracts the red channel and attempts to find and plot the local maxima but it fails with the error:

> error: findpeaks: DATA must be a vector of at least 3 elements

Here is my simple code:

```
pkg load image;
pkg load signal;

i = imread('foo.jpg');

% Get red channel
red = i(:,:,1);

% Attempt to find and plot peaks
findpeaks(red);
% Error on the above line: error: findpeaks: DATA must be a vector of at least 3 elements
```

Comment: How do you define a peak? You'll find different implementations here on Stackoverflow if you sear for "Find local maximas in image". Btw: findpeaks works on vectors, not matrices.

Comment: [`imregionalmax`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) or [`Fast 2D Peak Finder`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder) may be what you are looking for.